# Google Script to import Amazon Ratings on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, urlfetch

I want to use Google Scripts to import the number of ratings of an Amazon product for **each star rating** (x 5-star-ratings, y 4-star-ratings, z 3-star-ratings, etc.).

[image: Screenshot of Amazon Product Review Page]

I use the script below on [this webpage (already filtered for 1 star ratings)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08CDQ6VBG) but I get "No ratings found"

```
function getRatings(url) {   
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var match = content.match(/<div data-hook="cr-filter-info-review-rating-count" class="a-row a-spacing-base a-size-base".*>([^<]*)<\/div>/);
  return match && match [1] ? match[1] : 'No ratings found';
}
```

Instead, if I use this other script on the same page I am able to gather the total number of ratings (but not only the 1 stars).

```
function totalReviewcount(url) {   
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var match = content.match(/<span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary".*>([^<]*)<\/span>/);
  return match && match [1] ? match[1] : 'No reviews yet';
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: At this time the referred question doesn't help. If the ratings are added dynamically then you will have to implement a headless browser but that might not be an easy task. It's better to look for an API or a more specialized tool for web-scrapping.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I ask what do you mean when you say "the ratings are added dynamically"? And how can you tell if they are, by looking at the HTML code of the page?

Comment: Webpages content could be modified by events that are handled by web apis and JavaScript. Those events might not be triggered by grabing the webpage by using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. By the way some websites don't serve the same content to users than to things like `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.

Comment: How can you tell which elements can be grabbed using UrlFetchApp.fetch? 

This element is grabbed by `UrlFetchApp.fetch` with no problem for example: `<span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary"`

Comment: That is not something that can be answered in a comment. Please edit the question so it can be re-opened.

Comment: I just edited the question, but it's still not accepting answers. Should I post a new question and link it here?

Comment: Question aren't opened automatically after they were edited, they are put in a review queue. Please be patient.

Comment: In the mean time, please read [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/1595451)